# FIX (quickfix) how to set which NIC/IP to use for the FIX session

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I am about to write a trading application using the FIX protocol (QuickFix for C++). The computer has 6 NIC card configured.  How do I let my FIX application (acting as an initiator in the case) to use one particular NIC card (IP address) of the all 6 available? The initiator setting only let me set the target host/port, not source IP/port.

And, how to let it use 2+ NIC cards simultaneously (for load balancing purpose) within the same application?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Initiator only needs to know of the IP address with which it needs to connect. How should a packet reach that IP is the job of the lower network layers and the kernel network stack.

Regarding 2+ NICs, that should be handled by the kernel routing table or the routers, which come along the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup specific routes in your routing table.
Example:
route add -host  gw

Where  is IP address of the target machine to which you want to connect to.
 is the IP address of one of NIC you want to use.

Thus it will use that NIC card for quickfix session.
Hope this helps.